# add and remove items (sugestions) in combobox by search in sheet vba_excel

Tags: excel, vba

im using combobox to search in sheet and items depending of typing letters

adding is work with increase row with count of items

but remove the items didt match with value of comobox not work im using for each but the problem with the value of item in this for

the error message is :

> could not get the list property. invalid property array index

```
Private Sub customer_name_Change()
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, Rng As Range
    Set Rng = database.Range("A3", database.Range("A" & database.Cells(database.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
    Dim Item As Integer

    With Me.customer_name
        For i = 3 To database.Cells(database.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Text <> "" Then
                If LCase(Left(database.Cells(i, "A"), Len(.Text))) = LCase(.Text) Then
                    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, database.Cells(i, "A"))
                     If x = 1 Then
                        .AddItem Cells(i, "A")
                        .ListRows = .ListCount
                     End If
                End If
            Else
                .Value = ""
                .clear
                .ListRows = 0
            End If
        Next i
        .DropDown

      If .ListCount > 2 Then
          For Item = 0 To .ListCount

             If LCase(Left(.List(Item), Len(.Text))) <> LCase(.Text) Then
                  .RemoveItem Item
                  .ListRows = .ListCount
             End If

          Next
      End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are adding and deleting from a range, not a table.  Excel will keep null spaces that were deleted and continue to count them.  It's a glitch that has never been fixed.  Your best bet is to make a table and then use the column name instead of a range for your code.